# Intuitive idea of the Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to understand intuitively the notion of Lipschitz function.

I can't understand why bounded function doesn't imply Lipschitz function.
[image]

I need a counterexample or an intuitive idea to clarify my notion of Lipschitz function.

I need help

Thanks a lot

Comment: also assume continuity?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It means that your function does not explode at some point - made mathematically rigorous.

This idea can also be shown geometrically like so (picture from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity)):

[image]

The Lipschitz condition (or Lipschitz continuity) ensures that your function always remains entirely outside the white cone, so it cannot e.g. become infinitely steep at one point.

Concerning your picture: Think of the function $sin(1/x)$ (source [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%281%2Fx%29)):

[image]

You see that it is becoming infinitely steep at the origin (and would therefore run into the white cone!) but it is still bounded.

This condition is e.g. used in the theory of differential equations where it guarantees the existence and uniqueness of solutions to certain types of differential equations.

Comment: yes, but in every bounded function I can draw this kind of cone (see the picture of my question).

Comment: @user42912: No, you cannot: See my edit for clarification.

Comment: @user42912: Does this help you?

Comment: yes, now I got it! thank you very much!

Comment: It's a nice way of thinking. Thanks. But I am not able to relate root x with this line of thinking. Any help pls?

Comment: @Ramit $\sqrt{x}$ is not Lipschitz.

Answer (score 75):

A Lipschitz function is such that $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \alpha |x-y|$$ for any points you pick. Writing this as $$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \right|\leq \alpha $$

what we're saying is that the slope of the secant line joining $(x,f(x))$ and $(y,f(y))$ is always bounded above by $\alpha$. An example of a Lipschitz function is $\sin x$, or $x$. An example of a function which is *not Lipschitz but is bounded* is $$\sin (x^2)$$ over $\Bbb R$. This is because as we go further towards $+\infty$, the oscillation becomes faster, and thus the slope of the secant lines get nearer and nearer to vertical ones.

An example of a function that is *not Lipschitz nor bounded* is $\sqrt x$ over $\Bbb R_{>0}$. This is because if we fix $x=0$ and make $y$ very close to $0$, the slope of the secant line grows without bound.

Finally, we can give an example of a function which *is Lipschitz but isn't bounded*: $x+\sin x$  over $\Bbb R$. Its slope will never get larger than $1$.

Comment: Excellent explanation! +1

Comment: If a function has a derivative that is bounded, must it be a Lipschitz function?

Comment: @PeterOlson Assume $f$ has bounded derivative. By the Mean Value Theorem, for each $x,y\in\operatorname{dom}f$, what can you equate $$\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$$ to?

Comment: In case of root x, near zero, isn't the slope becoming zero? Can we still say the slope is increasing without bound? ( though I know it is not lipschitz, only trying to understand it intuitively).

Comment: Hi Pedro Tamaroff, can you guide us with the next please https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440926/measurable-functions-and-existence-decreasing-function

Comment: Is Lipschitz continuity then actually the same as $|df(x)/dx| < a$?

Comment: @asmaier I don't think a bounded first derivative is the same as the Lipschitz condition. 1. The Lipschitz condition does not require differentiability, 2. the Lipschitz condition requires every secant line to have a bounded slope whereas a bounded derivative corresponds to every tangent line having a bounded slope.

Comment: @user But maybe the other way round: Every function with a bounded first derivative is also a Lipschitz function?

Comment: @asmaier I think you're correct! See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1165431/is-a-function-lipschitz-if-and-only-if-its-derivative-is-bounded

Answer (score 7):

Look at the square root function on $[0,1]$ and its behaviour at 0.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the unitary circle, $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ how is the tangent line in $x=1$?

Answer (score 0):

With this version (just assuming boundedness) , any discontinuous bounded function forms a counter-example .[why?]

But if you also assume continuity , see the examples below/above.

Furthermore , you may even have differentiability and boundedness without Lipschitzness......

Comment: How could a function be differentiable without being lipschitz?

Comment: Look at Tamaroff's example $sin[x^2]$ ..Isn't it differentiable?

Comment: OK, I wasn't thinking about the derivative going to infinity.