# How can I prove $\frac{1}{x}$ is not Lipschitz on $(0,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that first, this function is Lipschitz if we have some $c>0, |f(x)-f(y)| = |\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}| = \frac{|x-y|}{|xy|} \leq \frac{1}{c^2}|x-y|$ making it Lipschitz at least on $(c, \infty)$ but how can I show if it is $(0, \infty)$, this is no longer true? It doesn't make intuitive sense to me because as long as $\frac{1}{c^2}$ where c is positive (i.e. $(0, \infty) > 0)$, the function should still be Lipschitz since our original function does not change.

Comment: If $c$ gets arbitrary small, then your Lipschitz constant $\frac{1}{c^2}$ gets arbitrarily large.

Comment: Ah yes that makes more sense. For some reason, I was stuck on the aspect that c is never quite 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution #1.** [A continuous and differentiable function is Lipshitz iff it has bounded derivative.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1165431/is-a-function-lipschitz-if-and-only-if-its-derivative-is-bounded) But differentiating $\frac{1}{x}$ gives $-\frac{1}{x^2}$, which is clearly unbounded in $(0,\infty)$.

---

**Solution #2.** Suppose it is Lipshcitz. As you have written we have $|f(x) - f(y)| = \frac{|x - y|}{|xy|} \leq M|x - y|$ for some $M > 0$. This implies that for all $x,y > 0$ such that $x \neq y$, we have $\frac{1}{|xy|} \leq M$, but this is clearly false as we can let, for instance, $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}$ and $y = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{M}}$.

Comment: It's a very helpful response but we have not learned about this part yet. Is there a different way to prove so? Edit: Oh wait we are allowed to use Calculus

Comment: @TreausreDragon see my edit.

Comment: Thank you! That is more akin to our understanding of Lipschitz so far!

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ was Lipschitz in $(0,\infty)$ then it would preserve Cauchy sequences. However, the Cauchy sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ is mapped by $f$ to the sequence $f(a_n)=n$, which is clearly not Cauchy.