# Is a non-differentiable function Lipschitz continuous if and only if its subgradient is bounded?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, lipschitz-functions, subgradient

It's well known that a differentiale continuous function is Lipschitz if and only if its gradient is bounded. ([Is a function Lipschitz if and only if its derivative is bounded?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1165431/is-a-function-lipschitz-if-and-only-if-its-derivative-is-bounded))

Can this result be generalized to non-differential case? The tricky thing here is to replace the gradient with Clarke subgradient (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke_generalized_derivative). In other word, is the following statement correct?

> Consider a continuous function $f(x)$ whose Clarke subgradient is $\partial f(x)$ on $x$. $f(x)$ is $L$-Lipschitz continous, i.e.
> $$\|f(x)-f(y)\|\le L\|x-y\|, \forall x, y\in{\rm dom}(f)$$
> if and only if $\|g\|\le L$ for all $g\in\partial f(x)$ and $x\in{\rm int}({\rm dom}(f))$, where ${\rm int}({\rm dom}(f))$ represents the interior of ${\rm dom}(f)$.

Comment: Yes, if the subgradient is bounded (as a set), then the local lipschitz norm is bounded. Hence, if you have a global bound on the subgradient, then you have global lipschitz function.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Seems specific enough to me.  Maybe could add a domain and "for all $x$ in domain", though I think that's reasonably easy to infer.

Comment: A convex proper function $f\colon X \to \mathbb R$ is Lip. On bounded subsets of the B space $X$ if and only if the subfifferential maps bounded subsets of $X$ to bounded, nonempty, subsets in $X^*$

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks for your answer. But when I tried to google the concept "local lipschitz norm", I found nothing. Could you kindly provide some references where I can find them?