# What is the interpretation / intuition of a lipschtzian function?

Tags: lipschitz-functions

What is the interpretation / intuition of a lipschtzian function? I mean, a continuous function is one that "does not show jumps", what is the significance of a function being lipschtziana?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/353276

Answer (score 1):

It is one that does not become arbitrarily steep.  $\frac 1x$ becomes steeper than any given slope as $x$ approaches zero.  It is not Lipschitz.